# How to insert data within XML tags

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have an already created XML file and I want to populate data within different XML tags and save the changes.

Below is the structure of XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Ashish:Request xmlns:N1="http://www.example.com/XY/XY/XY/XY/XY" xmlns:Ashish="http://www.example.com/XY/XY/XY/XY" xmlns:ABC="http://www.example.com/XY/XMLSchema-instance" ABC:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/XY/XY/XY/XY XYZ_XX.xsd ">
      <Ashish:MH>
        <N:FRM></N:FRM>
        <N:T></N:T>
        <N:RT></N:RT>
        <N:RTT></N:RTT>
        <N:MD></N:MD>
        <N:ACT></N:ACT>
        <N:TP></N:TP>
        <N:TRD></N:TRD>
        <N:SN></N:SN>
        <N:SV></N:SV>
      </Ashish:MH>
    </Ashish>
```

I will store data within variables and populate data within different XML tags as shown above.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you look at using XmlDocument Class? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks @JasonBayldon I tried using XMLDocument and I was able to achieve what I was trying to. Though few other things was also required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below mentioned is what I tried-

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Dim xmldoc As New XmlDocument()
            xmldoc.Load("XMLFile1.xml")
            Dim nodelist = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Ashish:MH")
            For Each node As XmlElement In nodelist
                Console.WriteLine(node("N:FRM").InnerText)
                node("N:FRM").InnerText = "TESTING"
            Next
            xmldoc.Save("XMLFile1.xml")
```